# React detect click outside component clearing my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-ref

I have an outsideAlerter component that functions elsewhere on my site. I am now using it on a repeatable component and for some reason it is clearing my state effectively breaking my desired outcome.

below is my wrapper component that detects if you click outside of its children

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

/**
 * Hook that alerts clicks outside of the passed ref
 */
function useOutsideAlerter(ref, onClickOutside) {
    useEffect(() => {
        /**
         * Alert if clicked on outside of element
         */
        function handleClickOutside(event) {
            if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
              //console.log(onClickOutside);
              onClickOutside();
            }
        }

        // Bind the event listener
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
            // Unbind the event listener on clean up
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, []);
}

/**
 * Component that alerts if you click outside of it
 */
export default function OutsideAlerter(props) {
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
    useOutsideAlerter(wrapperRef, props.onClickOutside);

    return <div ref={wrapperRef}>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

Below is my controller component, it handles state

```
const TableFilterDropdownController = ({style, rows, colKey, activeFilters, addActiveFilter}) => {
    const [tableFilterState, setTableFilterState] = useState(
        {
            state: INACTIVE,
            iconColor: "black",
            filter: "",
            filteredRows: [...rows],
            localActiveFilters: []
        }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        let state = tableFilterState.state;
        let localActiveFilters = tableFilterState.localActiveFilters;
        if (state === INACTIVE && localActiveFilters.length > 0) {
            setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, state: ACTIVE})
        }
    }, [tableFilterState.state])
    //filter out repeats and rows that don't match input
    useEffect(() => {
        let filter = tableFilterState.filter
        if (filter !== "") {
            let tempFilteredRows = []; 
            rows.map(row => {
                if (row[colKey].toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) && 
                !tempFilteredRows.includes(row[colKey])) {
                    tempFilteredRows.push(row[colKey]);
                }
            })
            setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, filteredRows: tempFilteredRows})
        }
        else {
            let tempFilteredRows = []; 
            rows.map(row => {
                if (!tempFilteredRows.includes(row[colKey])) {
                    tempFilteredRows.push(row[colKey]);
                }
            })
            setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, filteredRows: tempFilteredRows});
        }
    }, [tableFilterState.filter, rows])

    const onClick = () => {
        if (tableFilterState.state === DROP_DOWN) {
            console.log(tableFilterState)
            if (tableFilterState.localActiveFilters.length > 0) {
                //setState(ACTIVE)
                setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, state: ACTIVE});
            }
            else {
                //setState(INACTIVE)
                setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, state: INACTIVE});
            }
        }
        else {
            //setState(DROP_DOWN)
            setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, state: DROP_DOWN});
        }
    }
    //something here is breaking it and resetting on click outside

    const onClickOutside = () => {
        setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, state: INACTIVE});
    }

    let addLocalActiveFilter = (filter) => {
        let newActiveFilters = [...tableFilterState.localActiveFilters];
        const index = newActiveFilters.indexOf(filter);
        if (index > -1) {
            newActiveFilters.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            newActiveFilters.push(filter);
        }
        setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, localActiveFilters: newActiveFilters});
    }
    

    return (
      <TableFilterDropdown 
        style={style}
        color={tableFilterState.iconColor}
        state={tableFilterState.state}
        onClick={onClick}
        onClickOutside={onClickOutside}
        dropLeft={true}
        filter={tableFilterState.filter}
        setFilter={e => setTableFilterState({...tableFilterState, filter: e.target.value})}

      >
      
        {tableFilterState.filteredRows.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <CheckboxInput 
                value={item} 
                label={item} 
                key={index} 
                onChange={e => {
                  addActiveFilter(e.target.value);
                  addLocalActiveFilter(e.target.value)
                  }} 
                isChecked={tableFilterState.localActiveFilters.includes(item)}
              />
            );
        })}
      </TableFilterDropdown>
    );
}

export default TableFilterDropdownController;
```

And lastly below is the UI component

```
const TableFilterDropdown = ({style, state, color, children, onClick, onClickOutside, dropLeft, filter, setFilter}) => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("state change")
        console.log(state);
    }, [state])

    return (
    <div 
      className={`sm:relative inline-block ${style}`} 
    >
      <OutsideAlerter onClickOutside={onClickOutside}>
        <IconButton 
          type="button" 
          style={`relative text-2xl`}
          onClick={onClick}
        >
         <IconContext.Provider value={{color: color}}>
            <div>
                {state === DROP_DOWN ?
                <AiFillCloseCircle /> :
                state === ACTIVE ?
                <AiFillFilter /> :
                <AiOutlineFilter />
                }
            </div>
          </IconContext.Provider>
        </IconButton>

        {state === DROP_DOWN ? 
          <div className={`flex flex-col left-0 w-screen sm:w-32 max-h-40 overflow-auto ${dropLeft ? "sm:origin-top-left sm:left-[-2.5rem]" : "sm:origin-top-right sm:right-0"} absolute mt-2 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none z-10`} role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="menu-button">
            <SearchBar label={"Search"} placeholder={"Search"} value={filter} onChange={setFilter} />
              {children}
            
          </div>
          : null}
      </OutsideAlerter>
    </div>
  );
```

For some reason whenever you click outside the component the tableFilterState gets set to

```
{
                state: INACTIVE,
                iconColor: "black",
                filter: "",
                filteredRows: [],
                localActiveFilters: []
            }
```

Which is not intentional, the tableFilterState should stay the same, only state should change. I can't figure this out so please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `useOutsideAlerter` and pass `onClickOutside` handler it captures `tableFilterState` value and use it in a subsequent calls. This is a stale state. You could try this approach or use refs as described in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function):

```
const onClickOutside = () => {
  setTableFilterState(tableFilterState => ({
    ...tableFilterState,
    state: INACTIVE,
  }));
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. I'm gonna read up on this since I was banging my head against a wall yesterday. Thanks for your help!